# Simultaneous reading and writing from a collection in different threads in java

Tags: java, collections

Here is the scenario:
I have 3 lanes from which I want to move my boxes. Each boxes have a groupId. So the lane will be assigned to a group.
Hence, when I get a first move request with unique groupId, I'll create a list and add this request to that list, and then start processing the list. If I get another request with same groupId, I have to add to the same list
(This list is being used to process the requests in different thread),
else create a new list and assign a new lane and start processing.
Please suggest a collection in java which can help in implementing this efficiently.
Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If the `List<T>` needs to be mutated and read from multiple threads a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` might be what you're looking for. Anyway I'd implement *my* locking strategy if the usecase is complex enough.

> when I get a first move request with unique groupId, I'll create a
>   list and add this request to that list, and then start processing the
>   list, If I get another request with same groupId, I have to add to the same list

I think you're better off using a custom locking strategy with `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: I think I dont need thread safety here. There is a listener which will add the request to this list and there is a camunda process instance which is working on the same list in parallel. I am guessing, if I lock the list then I wont be able to add a new request to the list. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: @Abhishek I don't know the specific frameworks you'r working with, but you wrote "create a list", so during the creating operation, all the threads other than the one creating it, must be locked.

Comment: Agreed @LppEdd.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt `List` is a good data structure for your use case. Since you are passing data between threads, [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) seems much more natural.

As an example, here is implementation with following assumptions:

- there is 1 `box` producer, that:

  1) generates `box` with random `groupId` in the range between 1 and 3

  2) puts `box` to the **single** `lane`
- there are 3 `box` consumers and each one:

  1) receive `box` from the `lane`

  2) consume the box if consumer's `groupId` matches with box `groupId`
- no additional frameworks are used (only core Java)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Answer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> lane = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

     Producer p = new Producer(lane);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(1, lane);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(2, lane);
     Consumer c3 = new Consumer(3, lane);

     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
     new Thread(c3).start();
  }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> lane;
   Producer(LinkedBlockingQueue<Box> lane) { 
     this.lane = lane;
   }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { 
         lane.put(new Box(produceGroupId())); 
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // set interrupt flag
     }
   }
   int produceGroupId() {
     // generate random int between 1 and 3
     return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4);
   }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final int groupId;
   private final BlockingQueue<Box> lane;
   Consumer(int groupId, BlockingQueue<Box> lane) { 
     this.groupId = groupId;
     this.lane = lane;
   }
   public void run() {
     while (true) {
       Box box = lane.peek();
       if (box != null && box.getGroupId() == this.groupId) {
         consume(lane.poll()); 
       }
     }
   }
   void consume(Box box) { 
     System.out.println("Consumer " + groupId + " received " + box + " for proxessing.");
   }
}

class Box {
  private final int groupId;
  public Box(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
  }

  public int getGroupId() {
    return this.groupId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "<Box " + groupId + ">";
  }
}
```

If the goal is to have **3 separate lanes**, than implementation would be a little bit different:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Answer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     BlockingQueue<Box> lane1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Box>();
     BlockingQueue<Box> lane2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Box>();
     BlockingQueue<Box> lane3 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Box>();
     Map<Integer, BlockingQueue<Box>> lanes = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, BlockingQueue<Box>>();
     lanes.put(1, lane1);
     lanes.put(2, lane2);
     lanes.put(3, lane3);

     Producer p = new Producer(lanes);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(1, lane1);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(2, lane2);
     Consumer c3 = new Consumer(3, lane3);

     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
     new Thread(c3).start();
  }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final Map<Integer, BlockingQueue<Box>> lanes;
   Producer(Map<Integer, BlockingQueue<Box>> lanes) { 
     this.lanes = lanes;
   }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { 
         int groupId = produceGroupId();
         BlockingQueue<Box> lane = lanes.get(groupId);
         lane.put(new Box(groupId)); 
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
   }
   int produceGroupId() {
     // generate random int between 1 and 3
     return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4);
   }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final int consumerId;
   private final BlockingQueue<Box> lane;
   Consumer(int consumerId, BlockingQueue<Box> lane) { 
     this.consumerId = consumerId;
     this.lane = lane;
   }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) {
         consume(lane.take()); 
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
   }
   void consume(Box box) { 
     System.out.println("Consumer " + consumerId + " received " + box + " for proxessing.");
   }
}

class Box {
  private final int groupId;
  public Box(int groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
  }

  public int getGroupId() {
    return this.groupId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "<Box " + groupId + ">";
  }
}
```